# Why Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug can't log messages from dispatchLoopShutdown plugin?

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, zend-log

Why logs can be sent from dispatchLoopShutdown plugin as it occurs before Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendResponse() and any headers haven't been sent yet ?

I init logger resource in my bootstrap

```
  protected function _initLogger()
  {
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
    return $logger;
  }
```

and use it from anywhere

```
Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('test');
```

and it works up to dispatchLoopShutdown plugin execution point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the Firebug writer has his own plugin in the dispatchLoopShutdown to inject the data in the response. You should add your plugin with a lower priority (see manual).

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug` itself registers his `dispatchLoopShutdown` plugin (`dLSp` for short) during it first run, so to get this logger working in `dLSp` you need `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug`'s `dLSp` (`Zend_Wildfire_Channel_HttpHeaders`) to be already registered before calling logger in `dLSp`. You can achieve this for examle by calling `$logger->log('')` in your bootstrap